# ./program: cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux, architecture, debian, cpu

When I try to execute program, I get this error:

```
MyBookLiveDuo1:/opt/program# ./program
-bash: ./program: cannot execute binary file
```

There is output of objdump:

```
MyBookLiveDuo1:/opt/program# objdump -a /bin/bash
/bin/bash:     file format elf32-powerpc

MyBookLiveDuo1:/opt/program# objdump -a program
program:     file format elf32-little
```

Can I execute such file on my cpu architecture?

Comment: have you set the execute flag 'x'? try 'ls -l program' to check.

Comment: Yes, the permissions are "-rwxr-xr-x"

Comment: try `file /bin/bash && file ./program` . Maybe it will report something different about the types. Good luck.

Comment: Are you trying to run an ARM binary on ppc? If so you'll need an emulator.

Comment: "file" for program is `program: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, not stripped`. "file" for bash is `/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit MSB executable, PowerPC or cisco 4500, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, with unknown capability 0x41000000 = 0x13676e75, with unknown capability 0x10000 = 0xb0401, stripped`